# Yii sessions timeout in webservice

Tags: web-services, yii, session-timeout

I want to change timeout for sessions. I set the timeout 1 second.

whenever I sign in to system , I can use the signout service after even a minute, while it's just for logged-in users.

Note : I write my own code for sign in and sign out.

here is my code for signin and signout service :

```
public function actionSignin()
{
    $model= new Users();
    $model->scenario ="signin";

    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
      {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
        $model->validate();

        if($model->hasErrors()){
            if($model->hasErrors("username"))
                $result=array("status"=>$model->getError("username"));
            else if($model->hasErrors("password"))
                $result=array("status"=>$model->getError("password"));
        }else{

            $user = $model->get_user();
            $result['user'] =  $user;
            //// creating session
            $session=new CHttpSession;
            $session->open();
            $session['name']=$user['username']; 
            $result=array("status"=>ErrorManager::get("OK");                    
        }
    }else{
        $result=array("status"=>ErrorManager::get("no_data_submitted"));        
    } 
    $this->renderPartial("/print_result",array("result"=>$result,));
}




public function actionSignout(){
    $session=new CHttpSession;
    if(isset($session['name']))
    {
        $result = array("status"=>ErrorManager::get("OK"));     
        $session->destroy();
        $this->renderPartial("/print_result",array("result"=>$result);
    }
}
```

and there is session configuration in my config file (main.php) :

```
'components'=>array(
    'session' => array (
        'class'=>'CHttpSession',
        'cookieMode' => 'allow',
        'timeout' => 1
    ),
```

Please tell me What the problem is...

Comment: What's your point? You tried to set timeout after 1 seconds and it did not work?

Comment: yes, exactly that's my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use the exist login function which Yii has done to handle it. Just open file `protected/model/LoginForm.php` to see what you missing. Look at

```
public function login()
```

and this is what you were missing

```
Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration); // $duration is what you have to set
```

If you still want use the session to handle your stuff by your self, problem with session timeout, I think it was not just Yii problem, it should be refer to

[How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: The `duration` you set here is in no way related to the session timeout. It's the lifetime of the "Remember Me" cookie.

Comment: this can help me,in some other way
but is there anyway to manage session timeout too?